# SQL Server: Data between two dates

Tags: sql-server, join, range

Given that there are two dates like 2012-07-08 and 2013-02-06. I need to count record of each user for every month. If there is no data for a user in particular month then it should return zero. The output should look like:-

```
id name   July-12 August-12 September-12 October-12 November-12 December-12 January-13 February-13
1  John      1        2          0            0         1           1           2      2    
2  David     0        1          0            1         1           1           2      2
3  Marry     2        1          0            0         0           1           2      2
```

Comment: You could use BETWEEN operator, something like .. 
Select count(*) from tableName WHERE createdate BETWEEN '2012-07-08' AND '2013-02-06' group by columnname

Comment: I had tried this but it excludes those records of user that does not have data in some months. But i want to include all months for each user. If there is no data for a user in that particular month then it should return Zero (0).

Comment: you may consider for self-join is a relationship.. May i know you schema if you want me to write  query :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `cant use BETWEEN` in case of date even if BETWEEN is `inclusive`.
For such cases it is better to use

```
startdate>='2012-07-08 ' and enddate<=2013-02-06
```

Because `2013-02-06` will be treated as  `2013-02-06 00:00:00` 12AM

Try this solution for your problem

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE(Month_Name varchar(25),ContactName varchar(50)) -- newly added

;WITH cte
AS 
(
     SELECT datename(month, @startdate) AS [Month_Name], @startdate AS dat
UNION ALL
     SELECT datename(month, DateAdd(Month, 1, dat)), DateAdd(Month, 1, dat) 
     FROM cte
     WHERE DateAdd(Month, 1, dat) < @enddate

)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT c.Month_Name,Cs.username
FROM cte c  CROSS JOIN usertbale Cs
ORDER BY c.Month_Name

SELECT c.Month_Name,c.username,ISNULL(tt.coun,0) as coun
FROM @temp c LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  datename(month,OrderDate) AS month_Name
           ,count(OrderID) as coun
           ,ContactName
    FROM tblpublisher p INNER JOIN tbluser  u ON u.userid=p.userid
    GROUP BY month_Name,datename(month,publishdate)
) as tt 
ON c.Month_Name=tt.month_Name AND c.username=tt.username
```

**EDIT**

Using `pivot` in above query you can achieve the exact result as in your question
[Check this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query)

Comment: Thanks Nithesh, but it seems that you did not read my question carefully. By applying above condition you can not get data for those users month wise whose record does not exists for that month... I need to split these two dates into month.

Comment: what is datename in above example?

Comment: system function. That will returns the month name of given date (provided month as first argument)

Comment: Can you please provide entire stored procedure by updating your solution.

Comment: sure. Let me know your tables from where you are taking user counts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33078/discussion-between-nithesh-and-neeraj)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you would require the below function to populate all dates between given condition and you may need to use pivoting to accomplish the task.

**Exec: SELECT * FROM dbo.GetDates('2012-07-08','2013-02-06')**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDates](@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
WITH 
 N0 AS (SELECT 1 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N0 T1, N0 T2)
,N2 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N1 T1, N1 T2)
,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N2 T1, N2 T2)
,N4 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N3 T1, N3 T2)
,N5 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N4 T1, N4 T2)
,N6 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N5 T1, N5 T2)
,NUMS AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NUM FROM N6)
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day,num-1,@StartDate) AS Date) as TheDate
FROM NUMS 
WHERE NUM <= DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate) + 1
);
```